# How to convert an nlfb object in a nls object

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression

I performed an NLS regression using `nlfb` from the `nlmrt` package. With 
`theta_scaled` being my initial parameter vector

```
> theta_scaled
[1]   0.60000    0.73624   -0.77962
```

and `residuals_function` a function which for each parameter vector would compute the residuals vector over my data, I used the call

```
results.nlmrt <-nlfb(start = theta_scaled, resfn = residuals_function, jacfn = NULL, trace = TRUE, lower = rep(-1, 3), upper = rep(1, 3), control = list(ndstep = 1e-5))
```

Results:

```
> results.nlmrt
nlmrt class object: x 
residual sumsquares =  7929.7  on  292 observations
    after  5    Jacobian and  19 function evaluations
 name         coeff          SE       tstat      pval      gradient    JSingval   
    a      0.999997        0.5262        1.9    0.05838      -6.343       403.5  
    b      0.707415       0.07837      9.027          0       323.8       67.68  
    c     -0.631532       0.01454     -43.44          0       894.8       9.951
```

I would like to plot some diagnostic plots, compute confidence intervals, predictions, etc. However, the `"nlmrt"` object doesn't have these fancy methods. I would like to convert the object to an `nls` object, but I can't use `wrapnls` because I  used `nlfb` instead of `nlxb` for my regression. Is there any way out?

PS if you're wondering why I cannot use `nlxb`, the reason is that I used NLS regression to calibrateg a complex fluid dynamics code. Thus I don't have a simple analytical formula for my model. However, since I can run the code for (more or less) arbitrary inputs and parameters, I could write a residuals function and use `nlfb`.

**EDIT** as G. Grothendieck rightly notes in the comments, I should have provided a working example. As far as I'm concerned, his example is ok. However, his answer doesn't work:

```
#G. Grothendieck's answer
library(nlmrt)
library(nls2)

# setup and run nlfb example
shobbs.res  <-  function(x) {
    if(length(x) != 3) stop("hobbs.res -- parameter vector n!=3")
    tt  <-  1:12
    res  <-  100.0*x[1]/(1+x[2]*10.*exp(-0.1*x[3]*tt)) - y
}
y  <-  c(5.308, 7.24, 9.638, 12.866, 17.069, 23.192, 31.443, 
          38.558, 50.156, 62.948, 75.995, 91.972)
st  <-  c(b1=1, b2=1, b3=1)
low  <-  -Inf
up <- Inf    
ans1n <- nlfb(st, shobbs.res)

# get nls object
ans <- nls2(y ~ shobbs.res(c(b1, b2, b3)) + y, start = coef(ans1n), alg = "brute")
class(ans)

# my additions
# confidence intervals don't seem to work
> confint(ans)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Error in prof$getProfile() : 'control$maxiter' absent

# apparently, there were convergence issues:
 > ans
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ shobbs.res(c(b1, b2, b3)) + y
   data: NULL
   b1    b2    b3 
1.962 4.909 3.136 
 residual sum-of-squares: 2.587

Number of iterations to convergence: 3 
Achieved convergence tolerance: NA

# even if I try to access the object's attributes, I can't find what I'm looking for
> str(ans)
List of 3
 $ m       :List of 16
  ..$ resid     :function ()  
  ..$ fitted    :function ()  
  ..$ formula   :function ()  
  ..$ deviance  :function ()  
  ..$ lhs       :function ()  
  ..$ gradient  :function ()  
  ..$ conv      :function ()  
  ..$ incr      :function ()  
  ..$ setVarying:function (vary = rep_len(TRUE, length(useParams)))  
  ..$ setPars   :function (newPars)  
  ..$ getPars   :function ()  
  ..$ getAllPars:function ()  
  ..$ getEnv    :function ()  
  ..$ trace     :function ()  
  ..$ Rmat      :function ()  
  ..$ predict   :function (newdata = list(), qr = FALSE)  
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "nlsModel"
 $ call    : language nls2(formula = y ~ shobbs.res(c(b1, b2, b3)) + y, start = coef(ans1n), algorithm = "brute")
 $ convInfo:List of 3
  ..$ isConv : logi TRUE
  ..$ finIter: int 3
  ..$ finTol : logi NA
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "nls"
```

Comment: code posted to SO's R tag should be self contained, minimal and reproducible so that anyone else can copy and paste it into their session to run it.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I understand your concern, however `residuals_function` is very complex and anyway I couldn't share the computer code that `residuals_function` calls to compute the residuals, since I don't have the source but only the executable. I tried to think of a fake problem, but all ideas I got were models which could be rewritten as a `formula` expression. Thus I was worried of answers which would only work because they recasted the problem in an "`nlxb`-like" way.

Comment: You are supposed to make up a simpler example to illustrate it if the original problem is too large, coimplex or proprietary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `nls` after running `nlfb`.

As an example, using the following modified from the examples section of `help("nlmrt-package")` :

```
library(nlmrt)

# setup and run nlfb example
shobbs.res  <-  function(x) 100.0*x[1]/(1+x[2]*10.*exp(-0.1*x[3]*seq(12))) - y
y  <-  c(5.308, 7.24, 9.638, 12.866, 17.069, 23.192, 31.443, 
          38.558, 50.156, 62.948, 75.995, 91.972)
st  <-  c(b1=1, b2=1, b3=1)
ans1n <- nlfb(st, shobbs.res)
print(coef(ans1n)) ##
##     b1     b2     b3 
## 1.9619 4.9092 3.1357 
## attr(,"pkgname")
## [1] "nlmrt"


# get nls object
ans <- nls(y ~ shobbs.res(c(b1, b2, b3)) + y, start = coef(ans1n))

confint(ans)
## Waiting for profiling to be done...
##         2.5%    97.5%
##  b1 1.742980 2.272051
##  b2 4.563383 5.357094
##  b3 2.981855 3.292911
```

**Added**

Note that this does not actually convert an object from nlfb to nls but rather performs a second optimization starting from the value found by `nlfb` producing a different value but perhaps that is good enough.

If not, this will convert `ans1n` to an `"nls"` class object.   We first use `nls2` to calculate an `"nls"` object.  The `"nls"` object so produced will work for most purposes but not with `confint`.  To get that to work we need to insert a `call` component into it as shown below (until this functionality is added to `nls2`).  Now `confint` should run.

```
library(nls2)
ans_nls2 <- nls2(y ~ shobbs.res(c(b1, b2, b3)) + y, start = coef(ans1n), alg = "brute")
coef(ans_nls2) # same as ans1n above but as nls object
##     b1     b2     b3 
## 1.9619 4.9092 3.1357 

ans_nls2$call <- ans$call # insert call component into nls object
confint(ans_nls2)
## Waiting for profiling to be done...
##      2.5%  97.5%
## b1 1.7430 2.2721
## b2 4.5634 5.3571
## b3 2.9819 3.2929
```

Comment: ah! writing the residuals functions as a `formula` expression! Brilliant :) I will test the solution and get back to you soon.

Comment: a question: shouldn't you set the number of iterations to 1, in the call to `nls2`?

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't seem to work. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Try using nls in place of nls2 as shown in revised answer.

Comment: Have added an issue to the nls2 project: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/nls2/issues/5  -- seems object produced by nls2 does not work with confint athough it does work in most other contexts.

Comment: As promised, I accepted your answer because it works when applied to your example. In my real case unfortunately it doesn't work: even if `nlfb` works fine, `nls` fails with message `Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) :  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates`. Since I don't have the source code of the fluid dynamics code I'm calibrating, I cannot really provide a full, reproducible example. is there some other way I could get help? Is there an help forum for `nlmrt` users? I can provide the full content of the object `results.nlmrt` [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] it contains a long (292 rows x 3 columns) Jacobian, but it would still fit in a SO question. BTW, also the call to `nls2` seems to work in my case: the only call which doesn't work (and which unfortunately prevents me from getting the CIs) is the call to `nls`.

Comment: We only used `nls` to get the `call` component but you could try reconstructing it by looking at the code at the end of the `nls` source.